Which iOS version is compatible with NSExtensionPointIdentifier key "com.apple.quicklook.preview" Quicklook Preview Extension
I am creating an iOS app to install on legacy iPads running iOS 9 and up, using XCode 13.4.1  which is the latest version that will support iOS below 11. The app is working fine but I just added a QuickLook Preview extension, and on iOS 10.3.1 it will not install due to the following error:

This app contains an app extension that specifies an extension point
identifier that is not supported on this version of iOS for the value
of the NSExtensionPointIdentifier key in its Info.plist. Domain:
com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain Code: -402653007

The NSExtensionPointIdentifier key in Info.plist is set by XCode automatically to "com.apple.quicklook.preview".
I want to set the iOS Deployment Target to the lowest iOS version that will support this configuration. The documentation does not provide any guide as to which NSExtensionPointIdentifier keys are compatible with which iOS version. Trial-and-error is limited by availability of legacy Simulators.
If anyone can point to documentation that indicates which iOS is supported by which NSExtensionPointIdentifier key, I would be very grateful. Thanks

I would write Apple, the docs imply iOS 4.0+
